# How to set cells range dynamically in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to pass a range into function dynamically. Starting from the specified row number till the end of *column A*

I'm using an `ADDRESS` function for it (it returns `$A$10` in my case), but the value which is returned by `ADDRESS` is not working as the first parameter in a range.

```
=COUNTIFS(
   ADDRESS(ROW(OFFSET(D7,COUNTA(D7:D),0)),1) : A,
   "H"
)
```

**Actual Result**: `COUNTIFS` return 0.

**Expected Result**: it's supposed to return a number of cells with "H" value (I have more than 0 of them, of course)

I guess that such range combination (ADDRESS + :A) doesn't work. How to set the range correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `INDIRECT` it:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(OFFSET(D7, COUNTA(D7:D), 0)), 1, 4)&":A"), "H")
```