# How to set dynamically "range" for google sheet when add data from panda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to append data from pandas to google sheets using google sheets api. checking the document, it require parameter *range*. so far I set the max possible value in google sheets, see similar post [how to set cells range dynamically in Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467792/how-to-set-cells-range-dynamically-in-google-sheets). but it does not solve my question. so anyway I can use dynamically?

```
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
            'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
            'values': df.values.tolist(),
        }
response = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=google_sheets_id, valueInputOption='RAW', body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body, range='A1:AA1000').execute()
```

Comment: Just `A1` should work.

Comment: nice, it works.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange),

> When appending values, this field represents the range to search for a table, after which values will be appended.

So, You only need to add the left top cell range of the table you're trying to append to.